# I wonder why connection between eclipse and 'oracle database' doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I tried to connect oracle sqlplus with eclipse

I already checked that I added the files 'ojdbc6.jar' and 'tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar' in 'WEB-INF/lib' folder

I also added `<Resource>` tag in Servers/Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost-config/context.xml

This is the context I added

```
<Resource
 name = "jdbc/oracle"
 auth = "Container"
 type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
 driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
 url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
 username = "scott"
 password = "tiger"
 maxActive = "50"
 maxWait = "-1" />
```

and this is the part of code related to connection with sql

```
 package sec02.ex02;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.Date;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 
 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
 public class MemberDAO {
    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private DataSource dataFactory;

    public MemberDAO() {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            dataFactory = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/oracle");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<MemberVO> listMembers() {
        List<MemberVO> list = new ArrayList<MemberVO>();
        try {
            
            con = dataFactory.getConnection();
            String query = "select * from t_member ";
            System.out.println("prepareStatememt: " + query);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                String pwd = rs.getString("pwd");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                Date joinDate = rs.getDate("joinDate");
                MemberVO vo = new MemberVO();
                vo.setId(id);
                vo.setPwd(pwd);
                vo.setName(name);
                vo.setEmail(email);
                vo.setJoinDate(joinDate);
                list.add(vo);
            }
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void addMember(MemberVO memberVO) {
        try {
            con = dataFactory.getConnection();
            String id = memberVO.getId();
            String pwd = memberVO.getPwd();
            String name = memberVO.getName();
            String email = memberVO.getEmail();
            String query = "insert into t_member";
            query += " (id,pwd,name,email)";
            query += " values(?,?,?,?)";
            System.out.println("prepareStatememt: " + query);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, pwd);
            pstmt.setString(3, name);
            pstmt.setString(4, email);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void delMember(String id) {
        try {
            con = dataFactory.getConnection();
            String query = "delete from t_member" + " where id=?";
            System.out.println("prepareStatememt:" + query);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Certainly I wrote it following what is written in book

First, what I expected is this

```
 id    password   name   email            joindate
 aaa    1234      tom    aaa@google.com      3/3
```

but all I can see is this

```
 id    password   name   email           joindate
 (nothing appears)
```

I added correct table in sqlplus, and save it, and I tried it while sqlplus is running and not running both.

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: what sqlplus has to do with eclipse ????

Comment: When connecting from Java SQLplus is not involved at all. SQLplus is just a command line tool to connect to an Oracle database. As to your problem: did you commit the data you added? Also, please provide a [mre]. The code shown doesn't output any data. Also provide DDL to create the table and DML to populate it. Also, you are catching and ignoring exceptions everywhere. You might want to consider using a little bit more robust exception handling than just printing it out

Comment: Are you creating a Web application? You wrote in your question: _but all I can see is this_ Where do you see that? Do you see it in your Web browser? Is class `MemberDAO` supposed to be a _Data Access Object_ (DAO) ?

Answer (score -2):

First try to make sure you are able to connect to Oracle database from Eclipse, try simple connect.Sample code below, I have used the proporty file but you can use direct connect as well.

```
Properties info = new Properties(); 
            info.load(input);
            String DB_URL = info.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            String tns_location = info.getProperty("tns_location");
            //System.out.println(tns_location);
            String wallet_location = info.getProperty("wallet_location");
            
            
            //System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:\\app\\aatif-pc\\product\\18.0.0\\dbhomeXE\\network\\admin");
            System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", tns_location);
            //System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=C:\\app\\aatif-pc\\product\\18.0.0\\dbhomeXE\\owm\\wallets\\aatif-pc)))");
            System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", wallet_location);          
            //String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:/@test";
            
                  
                OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
                ods.setURL(DB_URL);    
                ods.setConnectionProperties(info);
                OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection();
                
            System.out.println(DB_URL);
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }
```